# Where can I get requestId for Network.getResponseBody?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome-devtools, network-protocols

I`m trying to write some tools with chrome Chrome DevTools Protocol https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-enable.

I want get page `ResponseBody` and I don't know where can I find `RequestId`. So here is my simple Ruby code:

```
chrome = ChromeRemote.client

# Enable events
chrome.send_cmd("Network.enable")
chrome.send_cmd("Page.enable")

puts chrome.send_cmd "Network.getCookies"

# for this command I need RequestId ->
puts chrome.send_cmd "Network.getResponseBody"
```

For now I have empty result for `puts chrome.send_cmd "Network.getResponseBody"`.

Comment: You need to register a listener/callback for an applicable event e.g. [Network.responseReceived](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-responseReceived).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the `requestWillBeSent` event, which would give you both URL and requestId

Comment: Спасибо Данил за подсказку